# Create File Upload control dynamically in asp.net and read file data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to develop asp.net web application. I want to create file upload control dynamically (i.e., When I click "Add Button" system have to generate new File upload control in page) It must be partial render it should not to reload.

**UI:**

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="FileUpload.aspx" id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="addFileUploadUpdatePanel" runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AddFileUploadButton" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="FileUploadLabel" Text="Choose File:" runat="server" Width="155px"></asp:Label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="InvoiceMiscFileUpload" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="AddFileUploadButton" CssClass="wp_button" Text="Add" runat="server" OnClientClick="addFileUpload();" OnClick="AddFileUploadButton_Click"/>
<div id="MultipleFileUploadDiv"></div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

I have tried creating with JavaScript

```
var divElement = document.createElement('DIV');
var upload = document.createElement('input');
upload.setAttribute("type", "file");
upload.setAttribute("id", "file" + count);
upload.setAttribute("name","dynamicUploadFileUpload" + count);
upload.setAttribute("runat", "server");        document.getElementById("MultipleFileUploadDiv").appendChild(divElement);
document.getElementById("MultipleFileUploadDiv").appendChild(upload);
```

It is appending Control in UI perfectly.

In Back-end(.cs) file
When I try to read file count, I am not able to get exact file count.

```
Request.Files.Count
```

It is throwing "0" always, I am not able to get the solution.

And I don't know how to read uploaded file data from the dynamically created controls.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the file control dynamically through Javascript - keep the control on page and hide it. When you want to show the control just unhide(show) the file control. This will solve the issue.